# PHP and Sublime 2

Tags: php, sublime-text

Работаю в `Sublime 2`, все нормально, но один момент напрягает, строчка:

```
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die();
```

при билде выдает

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

И скрипт не выполняется, если убрать `or die();`, то скрипт выполняется, но строчка все равно есть, подключение офк правильное. Через браузер все нормально. Есть идеи, как это можно убрать?

P.S. Если работать без БД, то нет ошибок, т.е. только в этом ошибка.

На всякий конфиг:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\PHP\\PHP\\php.exe", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "php$",
    "selector": "source.php"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему сам. ) Проблема была при получении данных.